# apache tiles source directory - does it have to be WEB-INF?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tiles

I'm trying to use Apache Tiles (version 3) in a spring project. As far as I can see, all tiles-files should be placed somewhere under WEB-INF directory. I'm not sure about this, this is just my observation: when I set `war/WEB-INF/tiles/*.jsp` it's ok, when I set `war/tiles/*.jsp` (and change my tiles-defs.xml to point new directory) I get

```
org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/tiles/basic.jsp'.
```

All tutorials I found on the web show that tiles directory is under `WEB-INF\`. Can someone make clear whether tiles directory have to be under WEB-INF (or maybe if other jsp files have to be there as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't have to be in WEB-INF, but it is actually the recommended way, moreover this is absolutely not Tiles specific, this is a general JSP/Java EE recommendation. (because of security reasons, the WEB-INF folder is not accessible directly)

E.g. [here is](http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/jsp/tutorial-of-simple-jsp-tiles-application-without-struts/) a sample here where jsps our outside WEB-INF.

Comment: Thank you for important notes on WEB-INF directory. Anyway, still I can't explain why tiles fail to render the page, if it doesn't have to be in WEB-INF...

Comment: yes that is another question :) can you post your config files? (web.xml, tiles-defs.xml)

Comment: Ok, I solved the other problem. It was just missing .jar files. I thought that including as little as possible jar files is a good idea (not to make the .war to heavy), but it eats too much developer time to fix missing includes. Experience rules ;). Anyway thanks for you valuable answer!